# Why is running attached to the debugger so slow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What is going on that causes a debug build to be so much slower attached to the debugger compared to unattached? They are both the same exe running.

Edit: Most of the answers concentrate on breakpoints. I'm still running like mud without breakpoints, OutputDebugString, or anything in the watch window.  What about debug CRT, Runtime stack checks, and the debug heap?

Comment: Are you out of memory and disk trashing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it isn't `OutputDebugString` or piles and piles of breakpoints slowing everything down, try these:

- Windows debug heap - your process gets the debug heap if it is running under a debugger, no questions asked. To disable this when running under the Visual Studio debugger, visit the debugging page of the project properties and add `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` to the environment.

  (The Windows debug heap is a separate thing from the CRT debug heap. Your release build will get the Windows debug heap too, if it runs under a debugger.)
- The program loads lots of DLLs that have symbols. When a DLL is loaded, Visual Studio tries to find symbols for it. If there are symbols available, this can take time. There's not much you can do about this except to rearrange your program so that it loads DLLs less often.
- Check for any calls to `IsDebuggerPresent` - this can introduce arbitrary differences between running in the debugger and outside it.

(As a final throwaway suggestion - I would also be suspicious that exceptions (whether C++ or structured) might be a bit more involved when the process is being debugged. So if your programs throws a lot, maybe that could be a bit slower when it's being debugged.)

Comment: Excellent article about _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 http://preshing.com/20110717/the-windows-heap-is-slow-when-launched-from-the-debugger/

Answer (score 3):

If your debugger uses software watchpoints it internally step executes the code and checks these points and changes in variable values.

> The [VS] debugger can only support 4 hardware data breakpoints. If you use
>   expressions (a + b), debugger uses emulation mode.

Also, loading debugging information for libraries is slower and it contributes to the perceived execution time (response time).

[Reference](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/visualstudio.html)

Comment: Can you link your source? I'd like to read the rest of whatever is written there. thanks

Comment: I do not believe it! Single-stepping the code would perform so badly that the debugger would be useless. Are you sure? Single stepping means that for every instruction, a trap is generated which the OS kernel has to handle. The code would run like it's on a 4.77 Mhz IBM PC from 1981. :) I have never seen anywhere near such bad performance from the VS Debugger. I would think/hope that software breakpoints are implemented sanely, by the obvious method of replacing the breakpointed instruction with a break point trap type instruction (like int $3 on x86).

Comment: Ah, you're talking about data breakpoints; sorry. :) ^sheepish^

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a lot of logging via OutputDebugString? Output produced by OutputDebugString is received by a debugger, but ignored when not running under a debugger.

Comment: None in this project, but that was a major performance problem in my last one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons why running with the debugger attached can be significantly slower than unattached.  The most likely causes are

- Excessive number of break points
- Breakpoints which have expensive conditionals
- Too many trace points

The first thing to try is disabling all break points and seeing how that effects perf

Comment: Disabling breakpoints did make a difference, but attached is still ~3x slower than unattached.